# Is there something like date_diff in python to get tomorrow date ?

Tags: python, date, format

Here's my code

```
while x <= datetime.date.today():
   print something
```

How can I get `datetime.date.tomorrow()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`datetime.timedelta()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

When summing a `date()` and a `timedelta()`, only the `.days` attribute is used.